# SSRS Report Calculate Percentage in a summary table

Tags: reporting-services, pivot, percentage, summary

I am currently working on a report that has a summary I created using a table. What I would like to see are the total number of incidents that my group has received by week, the number of incidents that had to be returned for more information and then a percentage of what had to go back.  I have everything except the percentage.

I've been looking around here and I've tried various formulas but none are just right.

I used

```
=sum(iif(Fields!Open_Code.Value="Returned to Rep", (Count(Fields!Open_Code.Value="Returned to Rep")/(Count(Fields!Ticket_ID.Value))),0))
```

And another I got from here is

```
=Sum(Count(Fields!Open_Code.Value="Returned to Rep")) / Count(Fields!Ticket_ID.Value)
```

I am not sure if this is pertinent, but the "Open Code" field is an if then statement that I added to the data set to say, `if(unit = "RTR", "Returned to Rep", if(unit = " ", "No Issues", "fieldvalue"))`

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

=count(iif(Fields!Open_Code.Value="Returned to Rep", 1, Nothing))/Count(Fields!Ticket_ID.Value)